# How to get a shorter path to a file of my Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I have to share my OS X app, all the paths I have used for files used by project are linked to my username and the structure of my computer.

Is there a way to have paths related to my project so that once my project is shared the user may not get in troubles caused by 'file not found'.

I would move the used files of the project, into the project but then I don't know how to let this happen:

actual paths, what I use now:

```
/Users/???username???/XCode/projectName/fileName.txt
```

what I would like to use in my code:

```
function(path: fileName.txt)
```

how don't know how to make the paths this short, not caring about the users directories since the files I'm going to use are all inside my project.

I am very confused. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use a user's directory shortcut, e.g. `~/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an easy way to read files from your project directory:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *dataContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

So in `dataContent` you have the content of the file as an NSString instance.

Comment: This is what I needed! That you.